# Why do we add the flux operating in 2 different regions for finding electric field due to sheet of charge

Tags: electric-fields

For sheet of charge
Applying gausses law
Flux =E.ds = q•/E• 
Contructing cylindrical gaussian surface
The curved part does not contributes towards flux cz ds is perpendicular to E so cos90°=0...so flux contributed is 0
Flux contributed by 2 circular surfaces =E.ds each
For one side it will be= E.A (î)    eq 1 
 and the other one would be = E.A (-î)   eq 2
So net flux must be zero 
Net flux= eq1+eq2...=0
Plz explain why  in the actual derivation eq1 nd 2 doesn't not cancel but add up instead

Comment: You need to use MathJax. Folks can’t follow this

Comment: When computing flux, both the field and the area element have directions. You aren’t taking the outward normal vector into account.

Comment: It's also $E \cdot dA$ not $E \cdot ds$

Comment: @andrew ds is my area vector which is equal to magnitude of area and the unit vector pointing outwards to its surface

Comment: @Gsmith plz elaborate

Comment: Literally no one uses $ds$ for differential area. It's reserved for line integrals but whatever. The surface may be called $S$ but a small patch of area is usually $dA$. As long as you understand. I can post a comment answering your question and addressing the situation of a cube but it will have to wait for tomorrow for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\phi=\vec E .\vec A$$

The flux is a scalar quantity. There is no direction assosiated to it.

If the surface in question is a closed object (as it is, or else you cannot apply Gauss' law), then $A$ points in the outward direction (with respect to the closed surface).

So, it is $\phi_{total} = (+E)(+A) + (-E)(-A) = 2EA$.

Answer (score -1):

> For one side it will be= E.A (î) eq 1 and the other one would be = E.A (-î) eq 2 
>   So net flux must be zero Net flux= eq1+eq2...=0

Flux, the dot product of two vector quantities, $\vec E\cdot \vec A$, is a scalar quantity and not a vector quantity so it is inappropriate to write something like $E\,A\,\pm \hat i$ as the flux.

When Gauss is applied the quantity of interest is the net flux through a closed surface enclosing a volume ie the flux out of the volume or the flux into the volume.
In your example the net flux is $EA$ out + $EA$ out = $2EA$ out of the enclosed volume.

Comment: Then how come we cancel the fluxes in case of a cube..when charge is kept in the center .....if we donot consider î or -î (which is a part of area vector )

Comment: @Roopjoat24 If there is a net positive charge inside a cube there is a net flux out of the cube and the reverse is true for a net negative charge inside the cube.